# How often should a React component mount and unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on building a Pomodoro timer component involving a functional component and hooks. I've noticed that the component mounts and unmounts with every tick of the setInterval().  Is this expected behavior?  It seems strange for a component to mount and unmount that often so I'm wondering if I should be doing things a different way.  Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Pomodoro({ seconds }) {
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mount')
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimeLeft(timeLeft - 1);
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            console.log('unmount')
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, [timeLeft])

    return <code>{timeLeft}</code>
}

export default Pomodoro;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your component is not mounting and unmounting, it's just rerendering. A component rerenders any time its state or props update. And since you put `timeLeft` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` call, the callback will run any time `timeLeft` updates.

Note that [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is like a combination of the class-based `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, where an empty dependency array results in the same behavior as `componentDidMount` and otherwise behaves like `componentDidUpdate`.

The cleanup function (return value from the `useEffect` callback) runs both when the component unmounts and before the next execution of the `useEffect` callback (if you have a non-empty dependency array). This is similar to the class-based `componentWillUnmount` and `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle methods. See [Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) for more info.

So, in short, this is expected behavior and your component design seems to be fine.

Worth reviewing React's component lifecycle:

[image: React component lifecycle]

From: https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram

Comment: Thanks! This helps things make more sense.  I was under the impression that the 'cleanup' function at the end of `useEffect` ran when the component unmounted but I guess this isn't the case?

Comment: The cleanup function does run when the component unmounts, but also before the next time the `useEffect`'s callback is run (if you have a non-empty dependency array).